# How can I edit the profile settings using a phone's Internet browser?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, mobile-web

How can I edit profile settings using the Internet browser from a phone?

I want to change my profile picture to the image that is inside my phone. However, there is no "Edit profile & Settings" option for me to choose. I only saw "E-mail Setting" instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tap the `full site` link at the bottom right of the mobile browser page:

[image]
This will bring you to a view identical to the desktop view, having the `Edit Profile & Settings` tab.

Comment: Kinda icky if your phone's less than 1080p, but yeah, its about the only way to do it

Comment: On iOS Safari (iPad) this option currently isn't available and requesting the desktop site through the built-in Safari feature (hold refresh) doesn't work.  Download a browser which doesn't differentiate between mobile and desktop beyond requests for either - Puffin Browser is what I just used for this issue.  Was able to edit my profile from iOS